# Forgotten password link is not parsed properly

Tags: email, forgot-password

I have these set in my forgotten email email notifications template

```
{name},

To reset your password, please go to the following page:

{reset_url}

If you do not wish to reset your password, ignore this message. It will expire in 24 hours.

{site_name}
{site_url}
```

I get this output

```
foobar@gmail.com,

To reset your password, please go to the following page:

http://qux.com/?ACT={AID:Member:reset_password}&id=FPeUNsWS

If you do not wish to reset your password, ignore this message. It will
expire in 24 hours.

Qux
http://qux.com/
```

If you look at the url, {AID:Member:reset_password} is not parsed. Why?

Answer (score 1):

`{AID:Member:reset_password}` should be replaced with an action ID. If it's not, it means the action ID likely isn't present in your actions database table. Check your actions table rows against these. Add whatever may be missing.

[image: actions table rows]

Comment: Keep in mind the password reset functionality changed in 2.6.0, so the action method's likely changed because the flow is now different. Make sure to check the docs for the correct verify your reset templates are correct.